# How to specify a different version of the Standard DocLet in Maven?

Tags: java, maven, version, javadoc, doclet

Background: I have a project that compiles fine with maven in a machine with java 1.7.0, but the javadoc compilation fails in another machine, which has java 1.8.0. From the log of maven, I can see that one is using the "Standard DocLet version 1.7.0_40", while the other is using "Standard DocLet version 1.8.0".

The question is: **How can I tell maven to use the correct version of the Standard DocLet?**

I've already set the source code and target version both to 1.7 in the maven-compiler-plugin.

Comment: Hey Edu, did you figure out a way to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to take a look into the [documentation of maven-javadoc-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/examples/alternate-doclet.html) which describes as you should define the version for the doclets.

```xml
<project>
  ...
  <reporting> (or <build>)
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <doclet>org.umlgraph.doclet.UmlGraphDoc</doclet>

          <!-- <docletPath>/path/to/UmlGraph.jar</docletPath> -->
          <docletArtifact>
            <groupId>org.umlgraph</groupId>
            <artifactId>doclet</artifactId>
            <version>5.1</version>
          </docletArtifact>
          <additionalparam>-views</additionalparam>
          <useStandardDocletOptions>true</useStandardDocletOptions>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    ...
    </plugins>
  </reporting> (or </build>)
  ...
</project>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I have taken a look there, and I could only find how to choose an alternate doclet. I do not want that. I just want to use the standard doclet with a different (previous) version, as maven is defaulting to the newest available in the system, which is incompatible with my code.

Answer (score 0):

Having also [hit an issue with this](https://github.com/Activiti/Activiti/issues/2384) I dug into the maven-javadoc-plugin code and I don't think you can change the standard doclet version. You can specify a custom doclet but for the standard doclet it [uses your java version](https://github.com/apache/maven-javadoc-plugin/blob/34fccfb151ba0603556d57e1972ac897bce05a5e/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/plugins/javadoc/JavadocUtil.java#L742), presumably because the doclet implementation is part of your JDK.